# по клику на кнопке поменять текст в заголовке блока

Tags: javascript

```
var btnTurr=document.querySelectorAll('.uis-button_show-more-info');
for (let i = 0; i < btnTurr.length; i++) {
   btnTurr[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
   var x = document.querySelector('.search-result-text_full-group-hotel');
   var  OldText=x.textContent;        
   (btnTurr.innerHTML === 'Скрыть туры') ? x.textContent = 'Тест' : x.textContent=OldText;
})
}
```

выдает ошибку undefined, в чем ошибка?

Comment: Приложите HTML код

Comment: **undefined** из-за того, что нет пременной `OldText`

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.uis-button_show-more-info-active').each(function (index) {
  $this.click(function () {
    document.querySelector('li.search-result__list-item_opened-group>div>a.search-result-text_full-group-hotel').innerHTML = 'Test';
  })
});
```

как правильно обернуть в цикл чтобы работало для всех кнопок?

Comment: Приложите HTML код

Comment: судя по всему, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. надо было и вносить это как дополнение (нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса).